# Using Arrays in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, arrays

Im new to creating array and had a question. Say if you are creating an array and you dont know the total number of items that are going to be in the array. How do you use it without getting a null error. Note that I know I can add the array like so:

```
  Dim myArray("1", "2", "3", "4", "5") as string
```

Say for instance a user is entering name(s) into a textbox and I want to add them into an array. How would I accomplish this :

This what what I have so far and im getting a null error:

```
   Dim myArray() as string

   myArray(0) = "John"
   myArray(1) = "Jim"
   myArray(2) = "James"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the exception because you haven't define the length of the array. You can use ReDim to define the lenght, something like:

```
ReDim myArray(3)
```

But it appears that you don't know the length of array either at compile time or run time  then its better to use List or [ArrayList](http://www.dotnetperls.com/arraylist-vbnet). Something on the following line:

```
Dim list As New ArrayList
    list.Add("One")
    list.Add("Two")
    list.Add("Three")
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a crash in your second code example because the array doesn't have a defined size without putting a value inside the `()`.  To make the Array have a size after defining it, use [`ReDim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

In .NET it is preferable to use a [`List(of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#Y0) instead of an Array, unless you really must use an array.  This way you don't need to worry about the bounds, the List will grow as needed.

If you really need an array and are in .NET 3.5, then you can use [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Doesn't answer the question as to why the OP is getting an exception. Then, you could suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Like davisoa said, you can use the generic list class:

```
Dim list as new List(of string)
list.Add("John")
list.Add("Jim")
list.Add("James")

Console.WriteLine(list(2))
```

Comment: Except I gave him an example usage.